# Plotting Dataframe column - datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a datetime column with pretty random increments of time, format is:

```
time
2016-07-08 11:29:30
2016-07-08 11:30:02
```

Now I convert it to datetime:

```
df['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

Then I want to plot it using matplotlib, but it doesn't work:

```
plt.plot(df.['time'],df['y'])
```

I've tried converting it to an int, but then I can't figure out how to format it when plotting

```
 df['time_int'] = df['time2'].astype(np.int64)
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What does the rest of your data look like?  You probably first need to `resample` your data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html), so first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `time`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'y': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4}, 
                   'time': {0: '2016-07-08 11:29:30', 1: '2016-07-08 11:30:02', 2: '2016-07-08 11:31:52'}})

print (df)
                  time  y
0  2016-07-08 11:29:30  1
1  2016-07-08 11:30:02  2
2  2016-07-08 11:31:52  4

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)

print (df.set_index('time').y)
time
2016-07-08 11:29:30    1
2016-07-08 11:30:02    2
2016-07-08 11:31:52    4
Name: y, dtype: int64

df.set_index('time').y.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Another solution is:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df.plot(x='time', y='y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Works Great! Thanks for all your help.  The part I was missing was the set_index statement.