# How do I get actual dates to show up on my plot as they do in the pandas table I created?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

[image]I made a plot using data that I imported from excel into pandas. When I used the data to make a line chart, the x-axis plotted numbers and not the dates as specified in the data table. How can I adjust this so represent the appropriate format? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need `set_index`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38274187/2901002).

Comment: Can you post a sample of the dataframe? as @jezrael says it may be an index problem, but plotting with dates can be problematic for a number of reasons.